# Build a rotation matrix that rotates 30 degrees along the axis (1,1,1)?

Tags: matrices

[image]

Why does the following image equal what it equals?

[image]

Why does x,y,z equal that? 1/sqrt(3),1/sqrt(3),1/sqrt(3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by a direct application of [the Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).

In order to apply the formula, we need a *unit* vector along the rotation axis, $(1,1,1)$. In other words, we need a vector $\mathbf{k}$ which is parallel to $(1,1,1)$, but with the property that $|\mathbf{k}|=1$. This is the vector $(x,y,z)$ in the solution; note that 
\begin{align}
\left|\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}}=\sqrt{1}=1.
\end{align}

If we denote the aforementioned unit vector by $\mathbf{k}$, and the rotation matrix which we are trying to find by $\mathbf{R}$, we have by Rodrigues' formula that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I} + (\sin\theta) \mathbf{K} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf{K}^2,
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{K} = \left(\matrix{ 0 & -z &  y \\
                            z &  0 & -x \\
                           -y &  x &  0}\right),
\end{align}
and $\mathbf{I}$ denotes the identity matrix as usual.